# change innerhtml javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I'm new to javascript and can't figure out the best way to solve this problem.

I have a div called info.

I have dozens of videos, and am constantly adding new videos.

When I click a video, I want to update info.

So I was thinking I need a hidden div with the text, and getElementsByClassName for something like this:

```
<div class="video"><a href="./video1.mp4" target="videoplayer" onclick="showDescription()><div class="description"><p>description for video1</div>
<div class="video"><a href=./video2.mp4 target="videoplayer" onclick="showDescription()><div class="description"><p>description for video2</div>
<div class="video"><a href=./video3.mp4 target="videoplayer" onclick="showDescription()><div class="description"><p>description for video3</div>
```

and

```
function showDescription(){
var description = this.getElementsByClassName("description");
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = description;
{
```

That doesn't work. Is using getElementsByClassName a good way to do this, or can anyone suggest another way?

---

Here's the actual html I'm using:

```
<div id="videoplayer">
    <iframe name="VideoPlayer" width="80%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL5A2FB27789F71E63> </iframe>
</div>

<div id="info">
    <p>Welcome</p>
</div>

<div class="thumb"><p>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLF06E26B33B6A2F33" target="VideoPlayer"     onClick="changeInfo()"><img src="http://discolemonade.com/roku/images/thumbs/MusicVideos/MV-ThumbSmallPlaylist.jpg"></a>
    Hours of music videos, refreshed often.
    </p>
    <div class="longinfodiv">
    <p class="longinfo">this is the long version of the music video playlist info</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
function changeInfo() {
    var longinfo = document.getElementsByClassName("longinfo");
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = longinfo;
}
```

Comment: You are assigning a live HTMLCollection to a string property. Clearly that can't be right.

Comment: Try this: `Array.prototype.splice(description,0).join("\n")`

Comment: Can you show the full code? From what you're showing here, you're doing things incorrectly. You're using the getElementById() method but you don't have any IDs. What logic are you trying to employ?

Comment: @shmuli This will successfully change the video in the player, but I get [object HTMLCollection] for the info.

Answer (score 0):

First structure your HTML file properly:

```
<div class="video">
    <a href="./video1.mp4" target="videoplayer" onclick="showDescription()">Link</a>
    <div class="description">description for video1</div>
</div>
```

Then use the following script:

```
function showDescription(){
  var video = this.parentNode;
  var desc = video.children[1];
 document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = desc.innerHTML;
}
```